# Flutter: Lottie file crashes

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, lottie, after-effects

Problem: The Lottie files that I downloaded do not show properly.

Details:

This is a screenshot when I run the code:
[image_result of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnK4C.png)

And the actual image should be like this:
[image_actual image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oqi3q.png)

Code:

```
Container(
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.43,
  // color: Colors.red,
  child: Lottie.asset('assets/lottie/morning.json', width: 300, height: 300, fit: BoxFit.fill),
)
```

Package: `Lottie: ^3.1.0`

I don't know why this is happening.

- I have tried changing the size of the Container, or Lottie asset size.

```
Container(
   width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
   height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.43,
   color: Colors.red,
   child: Lottie.asset("assets/lottie/morning.json", fit: BoxFit.fitWidth),
),
```

I have also eliminated the size of the Lottie asset size, but still the file crashes.
Some file doesn't have this kind of issue.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehhc0.png)

I think the code has no problem.
Is there a regulation while downloading Lottie free animation files?

Comment: I'm using Lottie file inside the flutter_onBoarding_slider > background

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the width and height properties of the `Container` widget (300 in your case) are suitable for displaying the Lottie animation correctly. You might need to adjust these values based on the size of your animation.The BoxFit property determines how the image is fitted into the available space. In your case, you've set it to `BoxFit.fill`, which means the image will be resized to fill the available space while maintaining its aspect ratio. You might want to try different BoxFit values like `contain`, `cover`, or `fitWidth` to see if they produce the desired result.

**Edit**

For my part, I tried running the [animation](https://app.lottiefiles.com/animation/d17168ae-8b4c-48dc-b7e3-b8cf4b2165b1?panel=download) you have used in an android emulator. It worked well. I think the problem is not in your code. If you are using `IOS`,I think this animation is not supported. Please refer to this [document](https://lottiefiles.com/supported-features).

Comment: Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.43,
            color: Colors.red,
            child: Lottie.asset("assets/lottie/morning.json", fit: BoxFit.fill),
),



I have changed it, but still it crashes.
Also I have changed the option of the fit (cover, fill, contain).
Still it doesn't fix my problem... 

Comment: try this Container( width: 300, height: 300, color: Colors.red, child: Lottie.asset("assets/lottie/morning.json",),

Comment: Still that doesn't work... 

Answer (score 0):

Set width and height for your Container. If it not work, add properties BoxFit

Comment: Still that doesn't solve the problem... 

Comment: You can try this:
child: Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
         children: [
                        Lottie.asset('animation/main.json',
                            height: screenSize.height * 0.3),
                      ],
                    ),

Comment: set height 300 or 400, or you can measure the size of screen like me do

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but still that doesn't work....

Comment: my app still work so good....

Comment: There are some Lottie files that works fine, but the image that I want to use crashes...

Comment: I have faced it when i used react native. in fact some lottie animation cant be set height. Eample: Some animations increase in size from their original size => cant set width and height for it...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).